# Blutooth on HP Laptop with RTL8821CE adapter not working

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

I installed Ubuntu desktop LTS 20.04 on a new HP laptop and the OS was able to locate a WIFI driver through the additional drivers utility. WiFi works fine but the OS is not able to detect bluetooth hardware and it doesn't even show up in setting.

Not sure if there is an updated driver or a workaround to enable bluetooth.

Here's the output of **lspci**:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b61 (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 02ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 02ef
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode]
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02bc (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 02b1 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0284
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 02c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 02a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM108M [GeForce MX110] (rev a2)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
03:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
```

**lsusb**:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b62a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HP Webcam
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 3938:1031 MOSART Semi. 2.4G Wireless Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'**:

```
[   23.871631] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[   24.048034] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI(PXSX) defines _DOD but not _DOS
```

**systemctl status bluetooth**:

```
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead)
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

Feb 13 13:14:57 HP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Feb 13 13:15:51 HP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Feb 14 16:00:56 HP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Feb 14 21:28:51 HP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Feb 14 21:35:04 HP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
Feb 15 17:30:31 HP-Laptop systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Bluetooth service being skipped.
```

Many thanks for your help,

Comment: rtl8111... is an Ethernet adapter and has nothing to do with BT or WiFi

Comment: Can you update your question to include the output of `lspci`? This will provide specific information about devices in your system, making it more likely that someone can offer a solution to your problem 

Comment: @Matigo, lspci output was added. Thanks

Comment: @Pilot6, you're right. My HP Laptop has RTL8821CE which is combo adapter for Wifi and BT. I corrected the case description to reflect the correct information

Comment: The important info would be that from `lsusb: dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: @Jeremy31: the output of the suggested commands were added. Thanks.

Comment: It isn't showing a bluetooth device in lsusb results and I have no idea why it isn't

Comment: Well, that's exactly the problem. The BT hardware is not recognized. I had Win 10 installed on the same laptop before and BT was working perfectly fine, which means the h/w is functioning properly